# HAL UART transmission from RxEventCallback

Tags: stm32, hal

I've got a problem with sending data over UART using **HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA** function "being inside" **HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback** function more then one time (actually it doesn't matter what the transmission function I use - DMA, IT or just blocking mode, the transmission is executed just once). Meanwhile in the infinite function **while(1)** I can use **HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA** repeatedly, one by one. In the USART settings interruptions are enabled, global (including DMA) interruptions are enabled.
The question is how can I transmit data over UART from **HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback** more the one time? Maybe some of you have faced the same problem and solved it. Thanks!

By the way, I use STM32F401.

Firstly I started to seek the solution on the Internet. So I found that some guys had issues with the driver stm32f4xx_hal_uart and adding the string **huart->gState** = *HAL_UART_STATE_READY* in the end of the function **UART_DMA_TransmitCplt**. I thougth maybe there's a key, but no. I tried to do it - it didn't work out, after I used different transmission functions I'd written about before. No result, I just made a conclusion that it's not an issue in the DMA fuctions. It seems it's something generally related to USART functions.

Comment: Calling complex functions from an ISR (which the receive callback basically is) is almost always a terrible idea. You should set a flag or something in the ISR, and handle the transmission in the main loop.

Comment: @pmacfarlane, thank you for your answer! I couldn't agree more, you made a perfect point, and of course I realize that in my case I can do (and most probably will) without any transmissions in the ISR. I'm developing pretty complex project so it has to have its own debugging tool for simplifying the development process sake. Moreover timing is not crucial in this project. I suppose as soon as HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback is idle most of the time why can't I drill down on UART-related mechanism? ))))

Comment: You gave surprisingly few details. How frequently do you call UART_DMA_Transmit from the callback? From my experience, the problem number one with interrupt and DMA calls is timing (giving enough time for the data to be sent). The common problem number two is UART flags, if some of those flags are not cleared before the next transmission, UART will refuse to send anything. As an option, you can manually clear all UART flags before calling DMA Transmit (provided there are no timing violations). See if there are behavior changes.

Comment: I tried to make different delays between the transmissions, even from 50 ms to several seconds using HAL_Delay, also using a timer. In addition I would preventively say that the priority settings are correct. Afterall in the main loop HAL_UART_Transmist_DMA functions work perfectly even standing one by one (the string length for transmission is about 15 symbols). Anyway, thank you for your response, I'll try to clear flags manually inside callback.